# How to find a text using javascript or jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find a text from a paragraph using java script. 
Is there any code in JavaScript like we do in c# to find a text using "string.Contains("")" method.

Pls help...

Thanks Guys..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use str.search()

It will return the position of match and -1 if not found

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Answer (score 2):

equivalent of `string.Contains("")` is `indexOf` (returns -1 if subString doesnt exist in a string).

you can do :

```
var myString = "foo";
var myParagraphText = $('#myParagraphId').text();

if(myParagraphText.indexOf(myString) != -1){
    //myParagraphText contains myString
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply can you pls provide me a brief code. so that it is helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use string.indexOf("text") method which will return index of the "text" in the "string", return -1 if the text not found in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = $('p').text();
var regex = new RegExp('text to search for', "i");
if(regex.exec(n) != null) {
  // text found
} else {
  //text not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `search()` function

If it returns -1, the string is not present
Non-negative number means, string is present

```
var str="hello there";
alert(str.search("there"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For searching text inside a block element .

```
var str="your block"
str.search("text to find");


str.indexOf("text to find");
```

return the index of the text